# Custom Shape in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, shapes, android-xml

I would like to make a custom shape like in the image, but i have no idea how to start, could some body help please

[image]

Comment: which part of the image are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to deal with images.

you can create a seperate xml for the "head box" like this

```
<linear layout>
 <text view background="dark-grey" text = "o nuts"/>
 <image view src="blue line" />
 <linear layout>
   <image view src="donut" />
   <linear layout>
     <text view text="price" />
     <text view text="date" />
   </linear layout>
   <image view src="box_border_shadow_lines" />
 </lienar layout>
</linear layout>
```

and somethink similar for the articles...

attention this is no valid xml :) just some hints

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

The part you shown on the top in image is Action Bar u can start learning how to make an action bar. i have one example of Action Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Which one? the shape on the bottom of the image with the "Redeem" button?